# Weird Issue when using dataclass and property together

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, python-dataclasses

I ran into a strange issue while trying to use a dataclass together with a property.

I have it down to a minumum to reproduce it:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class FileObject:
    _uploaded_by: str = dataclasses.field(default=None, init=False)
    uploaded_by: str = None

    def save(self):
        print(self.uploaded_by)

    @property
    def uploaded_by(self):
        return self._uploaded_by

    @uploaded_by.setter
    def uploaded_by(self, uploaded_by):
        print('Setter Called with Value ', uploaded_by)
        self._uploaded_by = uploaded_by

p = FileObject()
p.save()
```

This outputs:

```
Setter Called with Value  <property object at 0x7faeb00150b0>
<property object at 0x7faeb00150b0>
```

I would expect to get None instead of

Am I doing something wrong here or have I stumbled across a bug?

After reading @juanpa.arrivillaga answer I thought that making uploaded_by and InitVar might fix the issue, but it still return a property object. I think it is because of the this that he said:

> the datalcass machinery interprets any assignment to a type-annotated
>   variable in the class body as the default value to the created
>   `__init__`.

The only option I can find that works with the default value is to remove the uploadedby from the dataclass defintion and write an actual `__init__`. That has an unfortunate side effect of requiring you to write an `__init__` for the dataclass manually which negates some of the value of using a dataclass. Here is what I did:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class FileObject:
    _uploaded_by: str = dataclasses.field(default=None, init=False)
    uploaded_by: dataclasses.InitVar=None
    other_attrs: str = None

    def __init__(self, uploaded_by=None, other_attrs=None):
        self._uploaded_by = uploaded_by
        self.other_attrs = other_attrs

    def save(self):
        print("Uploaded by: ", self.uploaded_by)
        print("Other Attrs: ", self.other_attrs)

    @property
    def uploaded_by(self):
        if not self._uploaded_by:
            print("Doing expensive logic that should not be repeated")
        return self._uploaded_by

p = FileObject(other_attrs="More Data")
p.save()

p2 = FileObject(uploaded_by='Already Computed', other_attrs="More Data")
p2.save()
```

Which outputs:

```
Doing expensive logic that should not be repeated
Uploaded by:  None
Other Attrs:  More Data
Uploaded by:  Already Computed
Other Attrs:  More Data
```

The negatives of doing this:

- You have to write boilerplate `__init__` (My actual use case has about
  20 attrs)
- You lose the uploaded_by in the `__repr__`, but it is there
  in _uploaded_by
- Calls to asdict, astuple, dataclasses.replace aren't
  handled correctly

So it's really not a fix for the issue

I have filed a bug on the Python Bug Tracker:
https://bugs.python.org/issue39247

Comment: I believe problem here is that you've type-annotaed `uploaded_by: str = None`, so now the dataclass machinery is looking for the default, but you've **also** implicitly done `uploaded_by = property(_anonmyous_setter)`, so it's taking it as the default value to pass to the constructor...

Comment: Yeah, remove the default value.... it works as expected if you pass a value instead of relying on a default. Not sure if this is expected behavior.

Comment: That probably shouldn't be a property at all. Also I wouldn't include the backing attribute as one of the fields, or you have to remove it from everything (e.g. it will still appear in the repr).

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can use `field(repr=False, ...)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's true, but by the time you've turned everything off I wonder what the point of listing it is...

Comment: True, honestly, I just don't think dataclass plays well with decorators here, if you want them to have the same name as the argument. The best bet is to simply give them a different name than the field. Maybe worth opening an issue on the cpython github

Comment: @MichaelRobellard I updated my answer with a potential work-around...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, unfortunately, the `@property` syntax is always interpreted as an assignment to `uploaded_by` (since, well, it *is*). The `dataclass` machinery is interpreting that as a default value, hence why it is passing the property object! It is equivalent to this:

```
In [11]: import dataclasses
    ...:
    ...: @dataclasses.dataclass
    ...: class FileObject:
    ...:     uploaded_by: str
    ...:     _uploaded_by: str = dataclasses.field(repr=False, init=False)
    ...:     def save(self):
    ...:         print(self.uploaded_by)
    ...:
    ...:     def _get_uploaded_by(self):
    ...:         return self._uploaded_by
    ...:
    ...:     def _set_uploaded_by(self, uploaded_by):
    ...:         print('Setter Called with Value ', uploaded_by)
    ...:         self._uploaded_by = uploaded_by
    ...:     uploaded_by = property(_get_uploaded_by, _set_uploaded_by)
    ...: p = FileObject()
    ...: p.save()
Setter Called with Value  <property object at 0x10761e7d0>
<property object at 0x10761e7d0>
```

Which is essentially acting like this:

```
In [13]: @dataclasses.dataclass
    ...: class Foo:
    ...:     bar:int = 1
    ...:     bar = 2
    ...:

In [14]: Foo()
Out[14]: Foo(bar=2)
```

I don't think there is a clean way around this, and perhaps it could be considered a bug, but really, not sure what the solution should be, because essentially, the datalcass machinery interprets any assignment to a type-annotated variable in the class body as the default value to the created `__init__`. You could perhaps either special-case the `@property` syntax, or maybe just the `property` object itself, so at least the behavior for `@property` and `x = property(set_x, get_x)` would be consistent...

To be clear, the following *sort of works*:

```
In [22]: import dataclasses
    ...:
    ...: @dataclasses.dataclass
    ...: class FileObject:
    ...:     uploaded_by: str
    ...:     _uploaded_by: str = dataclasses.field(repr=False, init=False)
    ...:     @property
    ...:     def uploaded_by(self):
    ...:         return self._uploaded_by
    ...:     @uploaded_by.setter
    ...:     def uploaded_by(self, uploaded_by):
    ...:         print('Setter Called with Value ', uploaded_by)
    ...:         self._uploaded_by = uploaded_by
    ...:
    ...: p = FileObject(None)
    ...: print(p.uploaded_by)
Setter Called with Value  None
None

In [23]: FileObject()
Setter Called with Value  <property object at 0x1086debf0>
Out[23]: FileObject(uploaded_by=<property object at 0x1086debf0>)
```

But notice, you cannot set a useful default value! It will always take the property... Even worse, IMO, if you **don't want a default value** it will always create one!

#### EDIT: Found a potential workaround!

This should have been obvious, but you can just set the property object on the class.

```
import dataclasses
import typing
@dataclasses.dataclass
class FileObject:
    uploaded_by:typing.Optional[str]=None

    def _uploaded_by_getter(self):
        return self._uploaded_by

    def _uploaded_by_setter(self, uploaded_by):
        print('Setter Called with Value ', uploaded_by)
        self._uploaded_by = uploaded_by

FileObject.uploaded_by = property(
    FileObject._uploaded_by_getter,
    FileObject._uploaded_by_setter
)
p = FileObject()
print(p)
print(p.uploaded_by)
```

Comment: Can you point out this inconsistency "so at least the behavior for \@property and x = property(set_x, get_x) would be consistent..."? It seems to be working the same now?

Comment: exactly, thank you. this is in fact the same behavior me and others noticed - dataclasses interprets the `@property` as a direct assignment (it translates as a `property` object essentially). I created a solution to work around this exact same scenario. Not sure if there's an easier approach, but the metaclass way seems the simplest ot me.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative take on @juanpa.arrivillaga solution of setting properties, which may look a tad more object-oriented, initially proposed at [python-list by Peter Otten](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2020-June/897506.html)

```
import dataclasses
from typing import Optional


@dataclasses.dataclass
class FileObject:
    uploaded_by: Optional[str] = None

class FileObjectExpensive(FileObject):
    @property
    def uploaded_by(self):
        return self._uploaded_by

    @uploaded_by.setter
    def uploaded_by(self, uploaded_by):
        print('Setter Called with Value ', uploaded_by)
        self._uploaded_by = uploaded_by

    def save(self):
        print(self.uploaded_by)

p = FileObjectExpensive()
p.save()
p2 = FileObjectExpensive(uploaded_by='Already Computed')
p2.save()
```

This outputs:

```
Setter Called with Value  None
None
Setter Called with Value  Already Computed
Already Computed
```

To me this approach, while not being perfect in terms of removing boilerplate, has a little more readability and explicitness in the separation of the pure data container and behaviour on that data. And it keeps all variables' and properties' names the same, so readability seems to be the same.

Comment: I think this alternative is a better solution to solve the problem, even thought the chosen answer expose the issue in the relation of `dataclass` with `property`. BTW, the link is seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified solution from original question using metaclass approach - hope it helps :)

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import dataclasses
from dataclass_wizard import property_wizard

@dataclasses.dataclass
class FileObject(metaclass=property_wizard):
    uploaded_by: str | None
    # uncomment and use for better IDE support
    # _uploaded_by: str | None = dataclasses.field(default=None)

    def save(self):
        print(self.uploaded_by)

    @property
    def uploaded_by(self):
        return self._uploaded_by

    @uploaded_by.setter
    def uploaded_by(self, uploaded_by):
        print('Setter Called with Value ', uploaded_by)
        self._uploaded_by = uploaded_by

p = FileObject()
p.save()
```

This outputs (as I assume is desired behavior):

```
Setter Called with Value  None
None
```

**Edit (4/1/22):** Adding clarification for future viewers. The [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) is a library I've created to tackle the issue of *field properties* with default values in `dataclasses`, among other things. It can be installed with `pip`:

```
$ pip install dataclass-wizard
```

---

If you are interested in an optimized approach that relies only on *stdlib*, I created a simple gist which uses [a metaclass approach](https://gist.github.com/rnag/d14b05680094b871935a9a30d43d5c0d).

Here's general usage below. This will raise an error *as expected* when the `name` field is not passed in to constructor:

```
@dataclass
class Test(metaclass=field_property_support):
    my_int: int
    name: str
    my_bool: bool = True

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        print(f'Setting name to: {val!r}')
        self._name = val
```

Comment: I didn't get the use of `dataclass_wizard`. Is it in the standard library?

Comment: @Diogo It's not in *stdlib*, but I have also separately implemented another approach which does, and which should have more or less the same end result. I've updated my answer above with a link to the gist in case you're curious.

Comment: I tried the `field_property_support` meta class of the gist, but it didn't work when there are default values for *all* the fields (including `name`). e.g.: When there are default values to all the fields and I do `v = Test()` it raises an error. Is that right?

Comment: @Diogo hmm, yes I believe you are right. to best of my knowledge, this is only a result of how field properties work currently -- that is, if you define a default value for a `name` field, then the following `name` property declaration overwrites the default value. The metaclass also ends up removing the final assignment of `property` object to the field, since this assignment causes confusion. Essentially, this means that a field property defined with a default value doesn't have a default anymore when `__init__` is generated by *dataclasses*.

Comment: The workaround for now is to define a class-scoped variable like `_name: ClassVar[str] = 'test'`, or alternatively without type annotation entirely. This should work in a class that defines default values for all the fields, i.e. including ones associated with properties as well.

Comment: note that I've also updated the gist to provide a more helpful message in such cases. I'd try running the example with `my_int: int = 2` for example. I also updated my answer above, as I now realized where the confusion about standard library was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, and with credit to *@juanpa.arrivillaga*, here is a proposed answer to the original question which uses decorators.

It works at least with the use cases shown, and I prefer it to the method described [here](https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/) because it lets us assign a default value using the normal **dataclass** idiom.

The key is to defeat the **@dataclass** machinery by creating the getter and setter on a 'dummy' property (here '`_uploaded_by`') and then overwriting the original attribute from outside the class.

Maybe someone more knowledgeable than I can find a way to do the overwrite within `__post_init__()` ...

```
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class FileObject:
    uploaded_by: str = None

    def save(self):
        print(self.uploaded_by)

    @property
    def _uploaded_by(self):
        return self._uploaded_by_attr

    @_uploaded_by.setter
    def _uploaded_by(self, uploaded_by):
        # print('Setter Called with Value ', uploaded_by)
        self._uploaded_by_attr = uploaded_by


# --- has to be called at module level ---
FileObject.uploaded_by = FileObject._uploaded_by


def main():
    p = FileObject()
    p.save()                            # displays 'None'

    p = FileObject()
    p.uploaded_by = 'foo'
    p.save()                            # displays 'foo'

    p = FileObject(uploaded_by='bar')
    p.save()                            # displays 'bar'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution of @juanpa.arrivillaga, I wrote the following function that makes it reusable as additional decorator:

```py
from dataclasses import fields

def dataprops(cls):
    """A decorator to make dataclasses fields acting as properties
    getter and setter methods names must initate with `get_` and `set_`"""
    
    for field in fields(cls):
        setattr(cls,
                field.name,
                property(
                    getattr(cls,f'get_{field.name}'),
                    getattr(cls,f'set_{field.name}')
                    )
                )
    return cls
```

Simple usage:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataprops
@dataclass
class FileObject:
    uploaded_by: str = "no_one"

    def save(self):
        print(self.uploaded_by)

    def get_uploaded_by(self):
        return self._uploaded_by

    def set_uploaded_by(self, uploaded_by):
        print('Setter Called with Value: ', uploaded_by)
        self._uploaded_by = uploaded_by
```

Output results:

```py
p = FileObject()
p.save()

# output:
# Setter Called with Value:  no_one
# no_one

p = FileObject("myself")
p.save()

# output:
# Setter Called with Value:  myself
# myself
```