# Is there really a bug in using python dataclass and property together?

Tags: python, properties, python-dataclasses

I have been here:

- [Weird Issue when using dataclass and property together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623952/weird-issue-when-using-dataclass-and-property-together)
- [Dataclasses and property decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079503/dataclasses-and-property-decorator)
- [Expected behavior or a bug of python's dataclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64787329/expected-behavior-or-a-bug-of-pythons-dataclasses)
- [Property in dataclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822445/property-in-dataclass)
- [What is the recommended way to include properties in dataclasses in asdict or serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64777931/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-include-properties-in-dataclasses-in-asdict-or-se)
- [Required positional arguments with dataclass properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69845745/required-positional-arguments-with-dataclass-properties)
- [Combining @dataclass and @property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551835/combining-dataclass-and-property)
- [Reconciling Dataclasses And Properties In Python](https://florimond.dev/en/posts/2018/10/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python/)

and could not find a direct answer to why this simple code works fine...

```py
class Vehicle:
    
    def __init__(self, wheels: int = 10):
        self.wheels = wheels # -> calls the setter method
    
    @property
    def wheels(self) -> int:
        print("getting wheels")
        return self._wheels
    
    @wheels.setter
    def wheels(self, wheels: int):
        print("setting wheels to", wheels)
        self._wheels = wheels

v = Vehicle() 
number = v.wheels # -> calls the getter method
print(number)

# last output: 10
```

...but this one does not (using `dataclass`):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Vehicle:
    
    wheels: int = 10
    
    @property
    def wheels(self) -> int:
        print("getting wheels")
        return self._wheels
    
    @wheels.setter
    def wheels(self, wheels: int):
        print("setting wheels to", wheels)
        self._wheels = wheels

v = Vehicle() 
number = v.wheels
print(number)

# output: <property object at 0x000002042D70DDB0>
```

even when the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) of `dataclass` tells explicitly in the beginning that the decorator `@dataclass` adds exactly the `__init__` method from the first code, i.e., this code:

```py
@dataclass
class Vehicle:
    wheels: int = 10
```

should add this `__init__`:

```py
def __init__(self, wheels: int = 10):
    self.wheels = wheels
```

#### Is that really a bug?

---

##### Short Note:

The private attribute `_wheels` is accessed only inside the `property`'s methods, as it should be (to isolate it).

I found in others threads (listed above) that this attribute is manipulated outside the methods, exposed as 'public', which is not desired in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in your code.

This code:

```
wheels: int = 10
```

sets `wheels` to `10`, then this code immediately after:

```
@property
def wheels(self) -> int:
    print("getting wheels")
    return self._wheels
```

sets `wheels` to a `property` instance.

`@dataclass` can't see the `10`. Your `10` is gone. The annotation remains, so `@dataclass` creates a `wheels` field, but your field's default value is a `property` instance, not `10`.

Comment: Ok, I understood. So, just to make it clear, is this affirmation correct?: `@dataclass` does not adds the `__init__` method described above (which signature's is using the default value with annotation), but actually it adds a simillar to this one: `def __init__(self, wheels: int = Vehicle.wheels):`.

Comment: @Diogo: Pretty much. `@dataclass` has no opportunity to see the `10`. (Note that the default is evaluated during execution of the dataclass decorator, so it won't pick up any further changes to `Vehicle.wheels` after decorator execution.)

Comment: Ok, thankyou for clarify. I think that should be more clear in the documentation ...

Comment: I came back here to say that, actually, this "issue" is in a recente discussion: https://bugs.python.org/issue39247 . There are some workarounds, but I think this remains as an issue in the relation `dataclass` vs `properties`

Comment: This [other thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2020-June/897506.html) also expose that.